# paypal HATEOAS link shows 0 dollars in the total amount for the first 5 minutes

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

When I first redirect a user to the subscription link it shows a total amount of 0, however it still charges the right amount to the customer.

[image: Text]

However if I were to wait 5 minutes before reloading the page, than it eventually shows the expected result.

[image: Text]

Wondering if anyone else has encountered this and has a solution for it. Thanks.

Note that this does not happen when using the "smart button".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are setting a start date/time for the subscription. Don't do this.